# Edit in mvc4 didn't work

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to edit this data in database and return new data
when i click on save button data doesn't change 
Here is controller :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(CustomPerformancePerformersModel customPerformancePerformersModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            int perfromanceId = Convert.ToInt32(TempData.Peek("CurrentPerformanceId"));
            customPerformancePerformersModel.performanceObj = db.Performances.Where(x => x.PerformanceId == perfromanceId).FirstOrDefault();
            db.Entry(customPerformancePerformersModel.performanceObj).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.EventId = new SelectList(db.Events, "EventId", "Name", customPerformancePerformersModel.performanceObj.EventId);
        ViewBag.VenueId = new SelectList(db.Venues, "VenueId", "Name", customPerformancePerformersModel.performanceObj.VenueId);
        ViewBag.Performers = new SelectList(db.PerformerPerformances, "Performers", "Name", customPerformancePerformersModel.performanceObj.PerformerPerformances);
        return View(customPerformancePerformersModel.performanceObj);
    }
```

and here is the html:

```
   <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.performanceObj.IsVisible, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.performanceObj.IsVisible)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.performanceObj.IsVisible, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.performanceObj.IsFeatured, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.performanceObj.IsFeatured)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.performanceObj.IsFeatured, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: is your Edit action being called?

Comment: can you paste your entire form html along with submit button and related javascript if any? Did you get break point on your Edit action?

Comment: I am guessing that by doing customPerformancePerformersModel.performanceObj = db.Performances.Where(x => x.PerformanceId == perfromanceId).FirstOrDefault(); you are overriding any changes towards the model. so at saves that what was already there. instead get the Performance from the db just like you already did, but into a local variable. then change it's data with the data from the CustomerPerformanceModel and then save that local variable

Comment: `customPerformancePerformersModel.performanceObj = db.Performances.Where(x => x.PerformanceId == perfromanceId).FirstOrDefault();` is fetching the object from the database. That will override any values inside `performanceObj` that were submitted in the Edit form.

Comment: @Forlani yes it called but it doesn't change in db.Entry(customPerformancePerformersModel.performanceObj).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

Comment: @StijnvanGaal so i should delete Linq statement !

Comment: @amalmansour don't delete the link statement. but instead of  setting the value of the statement to customPerformancePerformersModel.performanceObj, set it to a new variable. `var performance = db.Performances.Where(x => x.PerformanceId == perfromanceId).FirstOrDefault();` and then set the values of customPerformancePerformersModel.performanceObj in the performance variable. then just save the changes and it should work

Comment: Could you post your `GET` action method for this view?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        int perfromanceId = Convert.ToInt32(TempData.Peek("CurrentPerformanceId"));

        // There is no need to use Where. FirstOrDefault has an overload using predicates.
        var savedPerformance = db.Performances.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PerformanceId == perfromanceId); 

        // If the performance couldn't be found, then you could add the error to the model state and return it to the view.
        if(savedPerformance == null)
            return View(customPerformancePerformersModel.performanceObj);

        // Update properties from performance in database with new performance.
        savedPerformance.someProperty = customPerformancePerformersModel.performanceObj.someProperty;

        db.Performances.Attach(savedPerformance);
        db.Entry(savedPerformance ).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: this part didn't make sense to me `savedPerformance = customPerformancePerformersModel.performanceObj;` because you set it before that line then you set it again here.

Comment: @amalmansour if savedPerformance returned null, it means it has not been found in the database. You should check if perfromanceId has the correct value. KSib You are right. I wanted to set property by property. I will update

Answer (score 0):

Ideally your code will look something like the following:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int performanceId)
{
    var model = db.Performances.FirstOrDefault(m => m.PerformanceId == performanceId);
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost] //[HttpPatch] is technically correct, but most people I see tend to use only GET and POST actions.
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(CustomPerformancePerformersModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

You're retrieving the object from the database and tracking it in your `GET` action, modifying it using your form, then marking it as modified in your update action. This is strictly if you're using the MVC pattern, and will look different (see below) if you're using separate data and view models. You'll likely run into trouble with this approach if your view doesn't have fields (hidden or not) for all properties on your model.

Using separate data and view models, you'd have something like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int performanceId)
{
    var performance = db.Performances.FirstOrDefault(m => m.PerformanceId == performanceId);
    var model = new PerformanceViewModel(performance); //In this constructor, copy properties from your data model to your view model
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(PerformanceViewModel model)
{
    var performance = db.Performances.FirstOrDefault(m => m.PerformanceId == model.PerformanceId);
    model.Update(performance);
    db.SaveChanges();

}
```

With a sample view model:

```
public class PerformanceViewModel
{

    public PerformanceViewModel(CustomPerformanceePerformersModel model)
    {
        PerformanceId = model.performanceObj.PerformanceId;
        IsVisible = model.performanceObj.IsVisible;
        IsFeatured = model.performanceObj.IsFeatured;
    }
    public int PerformanceId { get; set; }

    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }

    public bool IsFeatured { get; set; }


    public void Update(CustomPerformancePerformersModel model)
    {
        model.performanceObj.IsVisible = IsVisible;
        model.performanceObj.IsFeatured = IsFeatured;
    }
}
```

Here you're creating a separate object (view model) that holds only the necessary data for your view, then using the data from that object to update your data model. I prefer this because it takes the ability to effectively directly modify the database, and because you can do any necessary intermediate processing (casting strings to bools, et cetera) in the Update(Model) method.